# dc.js row chart y-axis is out of order

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm setting up a series of linked visualizations using the dc.js library. Everything is going smoothly except for one little thing. I'm using a row chart to visualize a series of user ratings from 1 (worst) to 10 (best), however the ordering along the y-axis of the row chart is incorrect as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

The 10 rating shows up directly under the 1 rating, when it should show up after the 9 rating on the y-axis.

Here's my code for this chart:

```
rowChart
    .width(450)
    .height(350)
    .dimension(ratingDim)
    .group(ratingGroup)
    .elasticX(true)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(6)
    // The line below attempts to fix the scale issue, but when included
    // it breaks the visualizations, and nothing renders.
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 10]));
```

When I include the `.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([1,10]))` code, the console throws the following error: `TypeError: rowChart.width(...).height(...) ... .y is not a function`. Not sure what to make of the error. Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the row chart does not use a y scale. Yes, weird.

As for the wrong ordering, it looks like you're getting lexicographical (string) ordering rather than numeric. You don't show the dimension definition, but I would guess your csv or json parser is returning strings and you need to convert those to numbers.

The terse, idiomatic way to do this is with `+`:

```
var ratingDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d.rating; });
```

Comment: Perfect. Works. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: It's happened to us all. Probably good to have an SO question for it.